# Как использовать переменную php вызванную Ajax-ом?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

При нажатии на кнопку отправляется ajax запрос которая содержит значение id в php. А в php отправляется запрос к БД и получает в ответ данные в виде массива. Но проблема в том, что эти данные выводятся в ajax succes(data), но в самом php их использовать не получается.

Вот Ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'price',
    data: {"identify": id},
    error: function(){
        alert("Ошибка мой друг!");
    },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }   
});
```

А это код php страницы куда идёт запрос:

```
function actionGetRequestId(){

   if (isset($_POST['identify'])){ 
       $id = $_POST['identify'];
       $result = Services::getClassesByCategory($id);
       // Выводит массив данных в alert(data) в Ajax succes(data)
       print_r($result);
   }

   // Выводит undefined variable
   print_r($result);
   return true;
}
```

Comment: ЧТо именно вы пытаетесь с этими данными сделать в PHP?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Обработка ajax запроса происходит в controller, я хочу пройтись по массиву с данными и разместить их в отдельную view

Comment: попробуйте сделать `exit(print_r($_POST))` в самом начале контроллера.

Comment: @amirhan, пишите свой код в месте первого комментария и все будет работать

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Не получается. Тот же исход

Comment: а в DevTool гугл хрома на вкладке Network вы смотрели? Данные точно уходят? Вы точно видите там, что вы не отправляете пустоту?

Comment: @n.osennij Вот проверил. Когда нажимаю на кнопку отправляется запрос price. На странице в которой нажимается кнопка все данные выводятся в network. А страница на которой должны вывестись данные получает тот же запрос только пустой. Как с этим быть? И в чём причина? Спасибо заранее

Comment: "А страница на которой должны вывестись данные получает тот же запрос только пустой." - эти же данные должны отображаться в другом месте не через ajax?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Нет. Я хочу пройтись по массиву через foreach и добавить данные на страницу. Всё что делаю, выводится в succes Ajax. Только вот в php нет

Comment: "Только вот в php нет" - это вы о втором комментарии в кода в вопросе?

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Вc самом контроллере не получается выводить данные из массива. Но они отправляются в ajax succes

Comment: А как вы пытаетесь в самом контролере выводить данные? В браузере напрямую ссылку вводите? При этом отправляется GET-запрос, а не POST. А у вас в коде стоит условие `if (isset($_POST['identify']))`, то есть получаете данные из POST-запроса

Comment: @YuriyProkopets Когда нажимаю на кнопку в новом окне открывается адрес localhost/price. А в роутах прописал что при таком адресе обращаться к SiteController и определённый action которая и обрабатывает данные а потом подключает view где нужно разместить данные

Comment: В новом окне будет GET-запрос. И при єтом параметр `identify` уже не передается.

Comment: Покажите свой роут на контроллер